# Select 2 most recent dates from the table - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table like below

| ID_NUMBER | SALEDATA | SALEAMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-07 | 47,000 |
| 2 | 2020-03-25 | 51,470 |
| 3 | 2021-06-12 | 32,000 |
| 4 | 2018-10-12 | 37,560 |

I want to select the rows with the 2 most recent dates only. So my desired output would be like below

| ID_NUMBER | SALEDATA | SALEAMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-07 | 47,000 |
| 3 | 2021-06-12 | 32,000 |

Can someone please guide me on where would i start with this in SQL? I tried using MAX() but it is only giving me the most recent.

Thank you!

Comment: order by saledata desc limit 2 should work

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Standard SQL, you would use:

```
select t.*
from t
order by saledata desc
offset 0 row fetch first 2 row only;
```

Not all databases support `fetch first`.  It might be spelled `limit` or `select top` or something else, depending on your database.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, with the `rank` analytic function. Sample data till line #7, query begins at line #9. See comments within code.

```
SQL> with test (id_number, saledata, saleamount) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 1, date '2020-09-07', 47000 from dual union all
  4     select 2, date '2020-03-25', 51470 from dual union all
  5     select 3, date '2021-06-12', 32000 from dual union all
  6     select 4, date '2018-10-12', 37560 from dual
  7    )
  8  -- sort them by date in descending order, fetch the first two rows
  9  select id_number, saledata, saleamount
 10  from (select t.*,
 11          rank() over (order by saledata desc) rn
 12        from test t
 13       )
 14  where rn <= 2
 15  order by saledata;

 ID_NUMBER SALEDATA   SALEAMOUNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 2020-09-07      47000
         3 2021-06-12      32000

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

select top 2 from your data set order by the saledata column descending